# Reading values from text files without losing precision in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a data file of x and y coordinates, and I'm trying to read them into two double vectors in Qt. My problem is that the values are being cut off or rounded off after 3 decimal places, even though my original values go up to 6. My data file looks like

```
35.659569 139.723370
35.659546 139.723194
35.659527 139.723051
35.659523 139.722909
35.659383 139.722946
```

My code is

```
QVector<double> v, v2;
QFile textFile (":/new/files/02262017newdata.txt");
if(textFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
  qInfo() << "opened file successfully";
  double a, b;
  QTextStream textStream (&textFile);
  while (!textStream.atEnd()) {
      QString line = textFile.readLine();
      QStringList list = line.split(" ");
      if(list.size() == 2){
        a = list.at(0).toDouble();
        b = list.at(1).toDouble();
      }
        qInfo() << "a and b after using split is" << a <<" "<< b;
        v.append(a);
        v2.append(b);
   }
}
```

How can I read the values without losing precision?

Comment: It seems not reading but printing problem. Also note that some error isn't avoidable due to difference of decimal and binary fractions. Read and store as string in order to avoid losing precision.

Comment: Are you sure they are being cut off or are they just being displayed rounded? qDebug(), qInfo() could have formatting flags controlling how they are printed. Put a break point and review the content of the stack for `a` and `b`. I believe you will see your full values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not losing precision. Problem is in `qInfo()`. Try setting precision in `qInfo()` using `qSetRealNumberPrecision()`

Replace this line:

```
qInfo() << "a and b after using split is" << a <<" "<< b;
```

with:

```
qInfo() << "a and b after using split is"<< qSetRealNumberPrecision(8) << a <<" "<< b;
```